# Highlight just one single row in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, variables

I have a table with lots of rows. The table is there so people can grab data quickly via copy/paste. Trouble is you can easily lose track of where you last grabbed the text from (ie. which row). So I want a function where when you double click on a row (to highlight some text to copy) it then simply highlights the row and stays highlighted until you double click again.

I'm pretty keen to use Jquery.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
           $("tr").dblclick ( function() {
                var foo = (this);
                $(foo).css("background-color","#333");
                $(foo).css("color","white");
            });
            $("tr").mouseleave ( function() {
                var foo = (this);
                $(foo).css("background-color","#333");
                $(foo).css("color","white");
            });
```

The double click works. But the mouse leave highlights every row. Can I assign one variable to that row I've double clicked, then apply the `.mouseleave`function only to to that? Or is there another function that's better for what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: The reason I have .mouseleave is because whenever the mouse exits the element area the css applied disappears.

Comment: I got what I wanted working here - however it won't work in my IDE - http://jsfiddle.net/c79Er/

Answer (score 2):

```
 $("tr").dblclick ( function() {


// Unselect the previous selected row Logic
$(this).siblings().removeClass("Clicked");//Assuming the <tr> are at same level.

 //$(this).parent().children("tr").not(this).removeClass(".Clicked");    

 $(this).toggleClass("Clicked");

});
```

and change the  `$("tr").mouseleave ( function() {});` to `$("document").on( "mouseleave","tr.Clicked",function() {});`

Also, its good to have the css like-

```
.Clicked{
background-color : #333;
color : white;

}
```

Comment: $("tr.Clicked").mouseleave will not work. because clicked class is added dynamically and mouse leave is assigned before the class is added.
You must apply delegation on your example.

Comment: Its wrong now too.. its same as old one. As simple .on will act as event binding. Just go through this  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Or just add a check on mouseleave function that it has class clicked or not. like $("tr").on( "mouseleave",function() { if($(this).hasClass('.Clicked')){ /*do stuff */ }});

Answer (score 0):

You can add one flag to identify which one is double clicked. And if the flag is true than only apply mouseleave function.

You must also apply [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method if you assigning event in such case. like all tr or all li.

Plus I didn't got the meaning of mouseleave event here as you are doing same as dblclick event.

```
   var allTr=$('#tableId').find('tr');
    $('#tableId').on('.dblclick','tr',function() {
        var foo = $(this);

        //to remove css and attribute from privous selected tr
        allTr.css({"background-color","#333","color","white"}).removeData('clicked')
       //if you want to remove css when you double click again on same tr than use this if condition other wise dont use.
       if(!foo.data('clicked')){
           foo .css({"background-color","#333","color","white"}).data('clicked',true);
       }
    }).on('mouseleave','tr',function() {
        var foo = $(this);
        if(foo.data('clicked')){
          foo .css({"background-color","#333","color","white"});
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey Sudhanshu, my logic was that when the mouseleaves it will stay that colour. Trouble is it applies itself to every tr in the table. So I thought If I could assign the row that has been double clicked as a variable, I could have mouseleave function only on the variable.

Comment: Although above code will work for you. But I dont think mouse leave is necessary as on dblclick you are adding css and there is no logic to make it normal again untill you double click on same tr or other tr. Just try without mouseleave . I think it will work for what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

best if u can use `JQuery UI Highlight`

```
$("#myTbl tr:first-child").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

Check  [Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)